# Loading composer-generated folder from Yii's main config

Tags: php, yii

I have a folder, that contains a library, that was created by composer (aka, the folder's name is `vendor` and there is an `autoload.php` file).

Can I use Yii's `import` section to autoload this library instead of `require`-ing it in the `index.php` ? If so, how? I tried making an alias to the `vendor` folder and then doing

```
'import'=>[
    'alias_to_lib_folder.autoload.php'
    'alias_to_lib_folder.*'
    'alias_to_lib_folder.autoload'
]
```

but none of those works.

Regards

Comment: You have to create a wrapper for it and then your import in config will work.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Do you have any links to some examples/docs about how a wrapper should look like?

Comment: There are few ways to do it. Like [Example 1](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration) , [Example 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load composer-generated folder from Yii's main config.

However where are few other ways to load it.

For example, you can import it in Controller.php like this:

```
<?php
    class Controller extends CController
    {

        public function init()
        {
            Yii::import('alias_to_lib_folder.autoload', true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought so, after reading the docs, but it's not working and I don't know why. I have triple-checked that the file exists and the path is the right one, but Yii throws this exception: `Alias "application.extensions.PayumYiiExtension.vendor.autoload" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.`

Comment: Nevermind, it was because I was trying to use that code before the `application` alias was befined by Yii. I have one more question: Right now I'm forced to use `use Path\to\some\Class`. Can I make Yii implicitely use that class when it's first used?

Comment: @alexandernst yii can autoload a namespaced class, but the namespace must be named in a way similar to naming a path alias. The doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#namespaced-classes